# clojure - extending types in non-vanilla ways

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm new to Clojure.

In Java I can do something like this extremely contrived example:

```
public abstract class Foo {
  public void sayHello(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
  }
}

public interface Fooable {
  public void sayHello(String name);
}

public class Bar extends Foo implements Fooable, Barable {
  ...
}

public class Baz extends Foo implements Fooable, Barable {
  ...
}
```

So, here we have two classes, implementing the Fooable interface the same way (through their abstract base class parent) and (presumably) implementing the Barable interface two different ways.

In Clojure, I can use `defrecord` to define types Bar and Baz, and have them implement protocols rather than interfaces (which, essentially, are what protocols are, from what I understand). I know how to do this in the most basic sense, but anything more complex is stumping me.

Given this:

```
(defrecord Bar [x])
(defrecord Baz [x y])

(defprotocol Foo (say-hello [this name]))
```

how would I recreate the abstract base class functionality above, i.e. have one protocol implemented the same way across multiple `defrecord` types, without duplicating code? I could of course do this, but the code repetition makes me cringe:

```
(extend-type Bar
  Foo
  (say-hello [this name] (str "Hello, " name "!")))
(extend-type Baz
  Foo
  (say-hello [this name] (str "Hello, " name "!")))
```

There has to be a cleaner way of doing this. Again, I'm new to Clojure (and Lisp in general; I'm trying to learn Common Lisp concurrently), so macros are an entirely new paradigm for me, but I thought I'd try my hand at one. Not surprisingly, it fails, and I'm not sure why:

```
(defmacro extend-type-list [tlist proto fmap]
  (doseq
      [t tlist] (list 'extend t proto fmap)))
```

`fmap` of course is a map of functions, i.e. `{:say-hello (fn [item x] (str "Hello, " x "!"))}` The `doseq`, applied to a concrete list of record types and a concrete protocol, does work. Within the macro, of course, it doesn't, `macroexpand` calls return nil.

So, question 1, I guess, is "what's wrong with my macro?". Question 2 is, how else can I programmatically extend protocols for types without a lot of repetitive boilerplate code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your macro is returning `nil` because `doseq` returns `nil`.

A Clojure macro should generate a new form using a combination of syntax-quotes (`` ` ``), unquotes (`~`), and unquote-splicing (`~@`) [reader](http://clojure.org/reader) macros.

```
(defmacro extend-type-list [types protocol fmap]
  `(do ~@(map (fn [t]
                `(extend ~t ~protocol ~fmap))
              types)))
```

Without using a macro, you have a few options:

```
(defrecord Bar [x])
(defrecord Baz [x y])
```

Use a simple var to hold the function map:

```
(defprotocol Foo (say-hello [this name]))

(def base-implementation
  {:say-hello (fn [this name] (str "Hello, " name "!"))})

(extend Bar
  Foo
  base-implementation)

(extend Baz
  Foo
  base-implementation)

(say-hello (Bar. 1) "Bar") ;; => "Hello, Bar!"
(say-hello (Baz. 1 2) "Baz") ;; => "Hello, Baz!"
```

If you move to [multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods), you can accomplish something similar with [clojure.core/derive](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/derive)

```
(defmulti say-hello (fn [this name] (class this)))
(derive Bar ::base)
(derive Baz ::base)

(defmethod say-hello ::base [_ name]
  (str "Hello, " name "!"))

(say-hello (Bar. 1) "Bar") ;; => "Hello, Bar!"
(say-hello (Baz. 1 2) "Baz") ;; => "Hello, Baz!"
```

Comment: Though it was staring me in the face, I didn't realize that the function maps in `extend` were just that: maps with proper function values. As disguised by `extend-type`, I thought they were method-like things without first-class status. I managed to ignore [the commentary](http://clojure.org/protocols): *Function maps are maps of the keywordized method names to ordinary fns ... this facilitates easy reuse of existing fns and maps, for code reuse/mixins without derivation or composition*. Simple made easy, indeed.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem, having discovered `extend-type` first; I wasn't thinking properly about `extend`, which `extend-type` derives from. I'm going to have to read up on reader macro syntax to fully understand the corrected macro, but I chose this answer as the correct one because it not only shows me the corrected macro but also that alternate valid ways exist to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @xobicvap If you want to address your comment to a commenter (duh), start it with  @*whoever*, as I have done here.

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1

Macros are just normal functions that are called at compile-time rather than run-time. If you look at the definition of `defmacro`, it actually just defines a function with some special meta-data.

Macros return *Clojure syntax*, which is spliced into the code at the point of the macro call. This means that your macro should return (quoted) syntax that looks exactly like what you would have typed manually into the source file at that point.

I find that a good way to design complex macros is to first declare it with `defn`, tweaking it until it returns my expected output. As with all Lisp development, the REPL is your friend! This approach requires you to manually quote any parameters being passed to your proto-macro function. If you declare it as a macro then all the arguments are treated as data (e.g. variable names are passed in as symbols), but if you call it as a function it'll try to actually evaluate the arguments if you don't quote them!

If you try this out with your macro you'll see that it doesn't actually return anything! This is because you're using `doseq`, which is for side-effecting computations. You want to use `for` in order to build up the syntax to do all of the `extend-type` calls. You'll probably need to wrap them in a `(do )` form since a macro must return a single form.

### Question 2

According to [the documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord), you can actually implement multiple interfaces/protocols directly within inside the `defrecord` macro. After your field declaration, just add the bodies of all the `extend-type` forms you would have declared.

```
(defrecord Bar [x]
  Foo1
  (method1 [this y] 'do-something)
  Foo2
  (method2 [this y z] 'do-something-else))
```

Comment: I hadn't realized macros were really nothing more than functions called at compile-time. They're still new to me and so I guess are still somewhat mysterious. One question for you, though- I'm learning Clojure partially through [Clojure Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013754.do); they state that implementing protocols inline is generally to be avoided aside from optimization, for a variety of reasons (inline implementations become part of the defined type and so can't be changed at runtime without redefining the type, etc.) Does this bear out with your experience?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the two questions you asked at the bottom have been pretty comprehensively answered, but you asked something interesting in the text of the question: "how would I recreate the abstract base class functionality above, i.e. have one protocol implemented the same way across multiple defrecord types, without duplicating code?"

If we look at the documentation for [datatypes](http://clojure.org/datatypes), two quotes jump out:

- Concrete derivation is bad

  - you cannot derive datatypes from concrete classes, only interfaces
- Tying polymorphism to inheritance is bad

Clojure datatypes intentionally restrict some features of Java, for example concrete derivation. So I believe the answer to your question really is, "you shouldn't". Multimethods or def'ing the functionality outside the defrecord and calling into it (like DaoWen's answer) should be preferred.

But if you really, really want to do exactly what you're doing in Java, you can use [gen-class](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class) to extend a class.

```
(gen-class :name Bar :extends Foo :implements [Fooable])
(gen-class :name Baz :extends Foo :implements [Fooable])
```

Note that this implementation is a bit of a hack (you can't test in the repl because gen-class only does something when compiling), and doesn't use the :gen-class key in the ns macro like you typically would if you really had to gen-class. But using gen-class at all is a bit of a hack.